# environment found but not defined theme download shopify

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, shopify, environment

I'm trying to download a new theme but get this

`% theme download environment was found but not defined`

Comment: Did you check if the theme ID you'd like to download is listed in local config file with env name?

Comment: development:
store: https:vino-io.myshopify.com/
theme_id: 128848953503
password: -------------